# Mongo distinct query returns several records one of which is "". But find null fails to find it

Tags: mongodb, distinct

I ran a distinct query on a collection. The query syntax:

```
db.Collection.distinct("dict.field")
```

I got a set of results - one of which was "" (null).

I then tried to find the record that had a null value for the field in question:

```
db.Collection.find({"dict.field": null})
```

To my surprise, no record was found.

No indexes are set on this collection other than _id.

The field in question is a dictionary.

What am I missing?

Comment: Check whether the field exists in all of your documents inside the collection.

Comment: Field exists. Even more, I can find the record in question by running a simple find with sort ascending. To avoid doubt whether it is null or a single space, I re-run the find query with " " instead of null. Can only find it with either search all and sort ascending or find with ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for `db.Collection.find({"dict.field": ""})` instead. Null and String ("") are considered different datatypes.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/